# Docker - Appdynamics - machine agent issue

Tags: docker, appdynamics

I cloned the image from https://github.com/Appdynamics/docker-machine-agent

and executed the `docker-compose up` command after the machine agent installation.

But I am getting below error while starting the machine agent.

> docker-compose up
>
> Creating docker-machine-agent ... done
>
> Attaching to docker-machine-agent
>
> docker-machine-agent | /bin/sh: 1: /opt/appdynamics/machine-agent//start-appdynamics: not found
>
> docker-machine-agent exited with code 127

Comment: Looks like the .zip you downloaded does not contain the command file (`start-appdynamics`) the docker build is counting on...

Comment: I downloaded the mentioned machine agent file form appd site "Machine Agent Bundle - 64-bit linux (zip)" and renamed it "machine-agent"

Comment: Did you check it contains the file your docker container needs ?

Comment: Yes i have verified the contents of the file and followed the instructions as mentioned